# Show the example belong to the Bessel potentials space (fractional order sobolev space), where $p=2$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

> If $\delta>-\frac12$, show that
> $(1-x^2)_+^\delta\in W^{s,2}$, where $s\in (0,\delta+\frac12)$.

Answer (score 1):

Find (or look up) the Fourier transform. In 1 D, it's essentially 
$$
\xi \mapsto |\xi|^{-\delta - 1/2} J_{\delta + 1/2}(\xi)
$$
up to scaling. Then use the known behavior of Bessel functions at $\infty$. This extends readily to the n-dimensional case.